# Block attribute statistics in Autocad C#

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

[image]
[image]

I have 4 block attributes in the drawing that ignore the first block. How to create statistics table according to "DK" and the 2nd column is the value according to "TCD" like image 2? I tried to do it and it didn't work!

```
[CommandMethod("Createstatistics ")]
public static void Createstatistics()
{
    Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    Database data = doc.Database;
    Editor ed = doc.Editor;

    Transaction trans = new OpenCloseTransaction();
    try
    {
        using (trans)
        {
            BlockTable bt = trans.GetObject(data.BlockTableId,OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
            
            PromptSelectionOptions opts = new PromptSelectionOptions();
            opts.MessageForAdding = "Select Block";
            //Get Object
            PromptSelectionResult opResult = ed.GetSelection(opts);
            if (opResult.Value.Count!=0)
            {

                SelectionSet slSet = opResult.Value;

                foreach (ObjectId obj in slSet.GetObjectIds())
                {
                    BlockReference blR = (BlockReference) trans.GetObject(obj, OpenMode.ForRead); DBObject oj = trans.GetObject(blR.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    AttributeCollection attCol = blR.AttributeCollection;
                    double value = 0;
                    foreach (ObjectId obId in attCol)
                    {
                   AttributeReference attref = trans.GetObject(obId,OpenMode.ForRead) as AttributeReference;

                        if (attref.Tag=="DK" && attref.Tag=="TCD")
                        {
                         // I dont know how to do from here!
                           
                        }

                    }
                    
                    ed.WriteMessage("kq" + value.ToString());

                }

            }

            trans.Commit();
        }

    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        ed.WriteMessage(e.ToString());
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each block reference, you have to get the attref.TextString for both "DK" and "TCD" attribute references. Then, you can store the results in a dictionary.

```
[CommandMethod("Createstatistics ")]
public static void Createstatistics()
{
    var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    var data = doc.Database;
    var ed = doc.Editor;

    try
    {
        using (Transaction trans = new OpenCloseTransaction())
        {
            BlockTable bt = trans.GetObject(data.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;

            PromptSelectionOptions opts = new PromptSelectionOptions();
            opts.MessageForAdding = "Select Block";
            //Get Object
            PromptSelectionResult opResult = ed.GetSelection(opts);
            if (opResult.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
            {
                Dictionary<string, double> statistics = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                foreach (ObjectId obj in opResult.Value.GetObjectIds())
                {
                    string dk = null;
                    string tcd = null;
                    BlockReference blR = (BlockReference)trans.GetObject(obj, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    foreach (ObjectId obId in blR.AttributeCollection)
                    {
                        AttributeReference attref = (AttributeReference)trans.GetObject(obId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                        if (attref.Tag == "DK")
                        {
                            dk = attref.TextString;
                        }
                        if (attref.Tag == "TCD")
                        {
                            tcd = attref.TextString;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dk) && double.TryParse(tcd, out double d))
                    {
                        if (statistics.ContainsKey(dk))
                            statistics[dk] += d;
                        else
                            statistics[dk] = d;
                    }
                }
                foreach (var item in statistics)
                {
                    ed.WriteMessage($"\n{item.Key} : {item.Value}");
                }
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        ed.WriteMessage(e.ToString());
    }
}
```